# É permitida análise/revisão de código?

Tags: debate, perguntas, escopo-do-site

Me deparei com duas questões na fila de primeiras publicações, mas fiquei com dúvida sobre tomar uma ação sobre as mesmas por pedirem expressamente **revisão e análise** nos códigos, pedindo "dicas", "melhorias" ou "esse código tá muito grande, tem como ele ficar menor com algumas gambiarras":

> [fiz um jogo da velha em c++, e quero implementar uma inteligência artificial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228791/fiz-um-jogo-da-velha-em-c-e-quero-implementar-uma-intelig%C3%AAncia-artificial)
>
> [Como melhorar um código fazendo ele de forma simples e mais clean?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228790/como-melhorar-um-c%C3%B3digo-fazendo-ele-de-forma-simples-e-mais-clean)

O que eu faço com essas perguntas? Afinal, não são literalmente perguntas e sim pedidos. O que devemos fazer com situações do gênero?

Comment: Não existe fila de "perguntas tardias", provavelmente você se confundiu e viu na fila de primeiras publicações: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/126017

Comment: E também em nenhuma das perguntas citadas eu vi alguma referência a algo como "ficar menor com algumas gambiarras". No geral, acho essas perguntas úteis para a comunidade, se bem respondidas explicando as modificações.

Comment: Temos até uma tag [tag:revisão-código]